# Javascript to change the position attribute to static of every style where position attribute is fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

During some web scraping with Selenium WebDriver with Chrome, I encountered a page that has fixed regions (they do not scroll but stay fixed relative to the window).  Oftentimes when I request that the web browser scroll to a particular control using Actions.MoveToElement() , the element winds up being obscured by one of the fixed regions.  When Selenium clicks on an obscured element, the fixed region steals the click and my control does not get clicked.

The fixed regions have a `class=SomeFixedPositionStyle`. To get around this, I'd like to have Selenium inject Javascript code to go through each style on the page and modify it to set `position:static` if it's `position:fixed`.  How can I do this?

I chose to not modify the class attribute of the fixed elements because the act of scrolling the page resets the class attribute to the original value that has the fixed style.

For example, take a look at http://www.ishares.com/us/products/239572/ishares-jp-morgan-usd-emerging-markets-bond-etf .  As you scroll up and down, do you see the bands on the top and the bottom are fixed?

When I try to scroll to element `//*[@id="holdingsTabs"]/ul/li[3]` (this is the "All" link in the "Holdings" section, it winds up underneath the lower fixed region and cannot be clicked on.

Comment: Could you make the problem reproducible for us? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a style rule into the page

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule("SomeFixedPositionStyle { position: static!important; }", 1);
```

Comment: It seems like this solution requires me to know all "fixed" styles ahead of time, right?  Is there a way to just iterate through every style and modify it if it's got "position:fixed" ?

Comment: Well only other option would be to loop over all the elements and check the position, that would be expensive. It seemed like you already knew the class.

Comment: There are two "fixed" styles I see on this page so theoretically it's possible to try your approach.  Since fixed regions could interfere with any control on any other page on any other site, I was hoping for a general solution to this problem which would ofcourse be more beneficial to the developer community.

Answer (score 0):

What usually helps in situations like this is *scrolling into view of an element*:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

---

You may also get rid of the "stickiness" by dynamically changing the "position" of the wrapper:

```
var wrapper = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.sticky-wrapper'));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].style.position = null;", wrapper);
```

Comment: Just tried this and it causes the screen to scroll to where the "All" link appears right under the top fixed region.  So the top fixed region captures the subsequent click.  When I was using Actions.MoveToElement() it scrolled underneath the bottom fixed region.

Comment: @sevzas okay, got it. Added one more option. Have not tested it, but hope, at least, the general idea would help. Thanks.

Comment: The class of the fixed regions alternates between 'sticky-wrapper' and 'sticky-wrapper fixed' depending on where the page is scrolled to vertically.  I found that if an Object is "class=fixed" I can change the position using driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.position = 'static';", driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("fixed"))[0]) but then I have to run this code before every click.